# How do you encapsulate setting a $scope value across multiple controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encapsulation

It's my first Angular project and I have multiple pages with view code that looks like this:

```
<!-- in myapp.com/kitties -->
<tr ng-repeat="row in kitties">
    <td>{{row.fuzziness}}</td>
    <td>{{row.meowLevels}}</td>
    <td>{{row.evilness}}</td>
    <td>{{row.redDotProgress}}</td>
</tr>

<!-- in myapp.com/princesses -->
<tr ng-repeat="row in princesses">
    <td>{{row.magic}}</td>
    <td>{{row.woodlandCreatureCount}}</td>
</tr>

<!-- in myapp.com/fairies-->
<tr ng-repeat="row in fairies">
    <td>{{row.friendship}}</td>
    <td>{{row.mischief}}</td>
    <td>{{row.wingColour}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to encapsulate out the behaviour of checking the backend API for the table data, checking local storage for the table data, and then putting that data into $scope.kitties, $scope.princesses or $scope.fairies. Each page has their own controller and I don't want to put that repeated code in each page's controller. Where can I put this encapsulated code? I tried a service, but I can't access $scope from the service. I don't think a directive works because I only want to set one value in the $scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** A service it's one of the good ways to do it, but you don't need to access `$scope` from it. Look below at this example:

```
app.factory('generalService', function($timeout,$http,$q,$location){

  var kitties= getYourKittiesFunction();

  var service={
     kitties:kitties
  };
  return service;
});


app.controller('yourController', function($scope,generalService{
  // you have generalService.kitties now
})
```

So, I've declared a service, where I get my data and I send this service as a reference to controllers, where I can use it by calling `.custom-property`

**2.** Another way it's to have a `mainController` in your `master page`. Declare there everything you want and it will be visible from every child controller across the application ( because of inheritance )

Example :

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
    <h1>{{text}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="childController">
        <h1>{{text}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>

app.controller("parentController", [ '$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.text= "Hello world";
 }]);

app.controller("childController", [ '$scope', function($scope){
    // $scope.text is visible from parentController
}]);
```

---

**UPDATE**:
I think I didn't understand well first time I read it and what you really want is to encapsulate your view code into something to share it across multiple pages

In order to do that follow these steps:

a. In order to do that create a controller called, for example, `magicalListController`, where you'll put your code to fill your arrays ( kitties, fairies and princesses )

b. Put that html code in a separate view

c. Include it in your pages

Example:

```
app.controller('magicalListController', function($scope){
  $scope.kitties=// get your kitties
  $scope.fairies= // get your fairies
  $scope.princesses= // get your princesses
});

   // View code it's exactly how you posted in
```

And insert into another view

```
 <div ng-include="'path to your view'" ng-controller="magicalListController"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could nest controllers. I wouldn't know how to make the service option work though, because I would need to have some getYourData() function which I could pass a kitties/princesses/fairies parameter. Is there any way to pass a parameter to the service function?